# Adjusting x axis on lattice levelplot when using a POSIXct

Tags: r, lattice, posixct, levelplot

I have a level plot with a POSIXct axis, and I'd like to adjust how the date is displayed, as well as the number of ticks. My example plot looks like this:

```
library(lattice)

Beg<-as.POSIXct('2015-01-01 14:00:00',tz='UTC')
End<-as.POSIXct('2015-01-10 14:00:00',tz='UTC')

x<-seq(Beg,End,by='hour')
y<-rep(1:5,10)
z<-rep(1:5,10)


levelplot(z ~ x * y)
```

I'd like to display the dates in a "%d-%H" format, and increase the number of ticks so we have two ticks per day (at 11 and 23 hours)

I've tried using the scales argument as listed in other examples, but am having issues with POSIXct

```
ByHour<-x[as.numeric(format(x,"%H")) == 11 |as.numeric(format(x,"%H")) == 23]
d<-strftime(ByHour, format="%d-%H")

levelplot(z ~ x * y, scales= list(list(x=ByHour))) #Does not work
levelplot(z ~ x * y, scales= list(list(x=d))) #Does not work
```

Comment: "The other examples"? Could you be any less specific?

Comment: Other examples = similar questions/ answers found on this site

Comment: Well, no one can say I didn't try to give you a clue, but some people are apparently irretrievably ... I can't say it. Not politically correct. Continue on with your blithe approach to knowledge.